# Get twitter screen name using twitter id

Tags: php, twitter

Is it possible to get twitter screen name through twitter id without using twitter REST API ?? I actually want to get twitter account profile image. Using screen name. As we can get profile image through following url.

```
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=original
```

I have twitter account id's in my DB. I wounder is there any way of twitter id to screen name conversion.

Comment: Why you don't want to use the API? It's the best way to do it

Comment: @TomaszKajtoch because of twitter API Get request limit.. (180 reqs / 15 Minutes Window)

Comment: Yeah, it is true but you must know that bypassing the limits may be inconsistent with the Twitter rules. The API has rate limiting but did you know that with single request you can get data for up to 100 users? That gives you 180 * 100 = 18000 users/15 minutes (6000 for app auth)

Comment: @TomaszKajtoch what if my website hits more than 180 times within 15 minutes.. Each time different page is accessed..

Comment: Also different tweets/profile-photos are displayed on each page.. Caching will not help.

Comment: You can use `account/verify_credentials` and `users/lookup` and cache the results to not repeat the requests.

Comment: @Zerquix18 account/verify_credentials - limit 15/15 Minutes and users/lookup limit is 180/15 Minutes... Why twitter is not developer friendly !!

Comment: Another way is to use per user access token but i think you don't have twitter app and your users didn't allowed that app to do this.

Comment: It's just to prevent abuse. Why you need to make more than 195 requests within 15 mins?

Comment: @Zerquix18 i have integrated my comment system with facebook and twitter authentication. Once user is authenticated he can comment on page. Any other user can view comments on that page.. Let say i have more than 400 products. Each product have different page. Users can comment on them. I  want to display twitter profile image with screen name against each comment.. I know there are other commenting systems like DISCUSS but client dont want to use that.

Comment: Then why don't you store the profile picture and screen name when they log in to comment as their Twitter account? And by the way, the limitations of 180/15 and 15/15 are per user logged in, not per app. A single user can make 195 requests between 15m.